# Visual Studio Code что-то с визуалом

Tags: visual-studio-code

Запускаю я Visual Studio Code и у меня начинает плыть картинка не знаю как это назвать вот фото[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Нифига себе, такое!

Comment: А че это за значок в левом нижнем углу? У вас какая операционка стоит? А то если у вас редкая ОС может у вас просто ломаная версия для нее, такое бывает. Или с другими прилагами тоже что-то не в порядке?

Comment: Воу. Пожалуйста, предоставьте дополнительную информацию: Система и её версия, видеокарта, версия видеодрайвера, версия DirectX, версия Microsoft Visual C++

Comment: Обычный виндовс ноутбук